# Using POP in swift to create a generic add function ()

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

***Update:*** This is just for learning POP. I know we can use <+> operator but I want to know what I am missing out

I am trying to create a swift generic function to add two elements:
- If elements as Numerals, then simply add them.
- If elements are Strings, then concatenate them.

Here is my code :

```
protocol NumericType {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

extension Double : NumericType {}
extension Float  : NumericType {}
extension Int    : NumericType {}

protocol Addable {
    func addGenerically<T>(element1: T, element2: T) -> T
}

extension Addable where Self:NumericType {
    func addGenerically<T:NumericType>(element1: T, element2: T) -> T {
        return (element1) + (element2)
    }
}
// This throws error: inheritance from non protocol, non class type strings
extension Addable where Self:String {
    func addGenerically<T:String>(element1: T, element2: T) -> T {
        return (element1) + (element2)
    }
}


class MyVC: UIViewController{

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let n1 = Double(3.4)
    let n2 = Double(3.3)
    let n3 = Addable.addGenerically(n1, element2: n2)
}
```

Any Ideas how to complete this and use this ?

Comment: I'm really unsure what you're trying to achieve here. Swift can already infer which `+` operator implementation to call based on the types you use it with. It will concatenate strings, and add numbers – so you don't need to create your own `addGenerically` function. You also cannot implement your function like this: `Addable.addGenerically(n1, element2: n2)` – that simply makes no sense as `Addable` isn't a concrete type, so you can't call static functions on it.

Comment: @originaluser2 : This is just for learning POP. I want to  know what I am missing out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is pretty much what the error says – you cannot have inheritance from a non-protocol or non-class type.

`String` is implemented as a `struct` in Swift, and structs don't have inheritance. You can't create a 'sub-struct' of `String`. Instead of this, protocols are used in order to define common functionality and provide a sense of hierarchy.

Therefore you'll need to use a protocol in order to constrain the extension, much like what you did with your `NumberType` protocol. For example:

```
protocol AddableString {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

extension String : AddableString {}

extension Addable where Self:AddableString {
    func addGenerically<T:AddableString>(element1: T, element2: T) -> T {
        return (element1) + (element2)
    }
}
```

However, this is pretty long-winded, and I'm not even sure how you're going to implement this function anyway – as you'd have to use it on an existing value, while not using that value in the addition. You simply cannot use it like this:

```
Addable.addGenerically(n1, element2: n2)
```

Because `Addable` isn't a concrete type, you cannot call static functions on it.

I would recommend simplifying your code significantly by merging your protocols into a single `Addable` protocol. This will allow you to define which types you want to be addable, and therefore which types you can use in your `addGenerically` function. For example:

```
protocol Addable {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

extension Double : Addable {}
extension Float  : Addable {}
extension Int    : Addable {}
extension String : Addable {}

func addGenerically<T:Addable>(lhs:T, rhs:T) -> T {
    return lhs + rhs
}

...

let n1 = 3.4
let n2 = 3.3

let n3 = addGenerically(n1, rhs: n2)
```

Although I would generally prefer not to pollute the global namespace with a new global function – you should consider making the function take a single `Self` argument instead in an extension of `Addable`, allowing you to use to add a given `Addable` by calling the method on another `Addable` (although this removes the generics, which you may not want for your demonstration):

```
protocol Addable {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func addGenericallyWith(rhs: Self) -> Self
}

extension Double : Addable {}
extension Float  : Addable {}
extension Int    : Addable {}
extension String : Addable {}

extension Addable {
    func addGenericallyWith(rhs:Self) -> Self {
        return self + rhs
    }
}

...

let n1 = 3.4
let n2 = 3.3

let n3 = n1.addGenericallyWith(n2)
```

Although note that all we've achieved here is re-implementing the `+` operator! Swift can already infer which `+` operator implementation to call based on the types you use it with – so you don't need to create your own `addGenerically` function.